# Python Pandas: Group files in a directory by similar filenames and concatenate dataframes in a specific order

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, sorting

My goal is to group .csv files in a directory by shared characteristics in the file name. My directory contains files with names:

- After_Source1_Receiver1.csv
- After_Source1_Receiver2.csv
- Before_Source1_Receiver1.csv
- Before_Source1_Receiver2.csv
- During1_Source1_Receiver1.csv
- During1_Source1_Receiver2.csv
- During2_Source1_Receiver1.csv
- During2_Source1_Receiver2.csv

I would like to sort these files into groups on the numbers following the "Source" and "Receiver" sections of the file name (as shown below) so I can later concatenate them.

Group 1

- Before_Source1_Receiver1.csv
- During1_Source1_Receiver1.csv
- During2_Source1_Receiver1.csv
- After_Source1_Receiver1.csv

Group 2

- Before_Source1_Receiver2.csv
- During1_Source1_Receiver2.csv
- During2_Source1_Receiver2.csv
- After_Source1_Receiver2.csv

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider something like: `glob` to read in all filenames in the directory, and store them in a DataFrame; use regex to extract Source and Receiver numbers from each filename into new DataFrame columns; then `groupby` or sort by those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says you want to do this in `pandas` so here is a `pandas` solution.

```
fnames = ['After_Source1_Receiver1.csv',
          'After_Source1_Receiver2.csv',
          'Before_Source1_Receiver1.csv',
          'Before_Source1_Receiver2.csv',
          'During1_Source1_Receiver1.csv',
          'During1_Source1_Receiver2.csv',
          'During2_Source1_Receiver1.csv',
          'During2_Source1_Receiver2.csv']

df = pd.DataFrame(fnames, columns=['names'])
```

I don't know what you want to do with your end results but this is how you group them.

```
pattern = r'Source(\d+)_Receiver(\d+)'
for _, g in pd.concat([df, df['names'].str.extract(pattern)], axis=1).groupby([0,1]):
    print(g.names)

0      After_Source1_Receiver1.csv
2     Before_Source1_Receiver1.csv
4    During1_Source1_Receiver1.csv
6    During2_Source1_Receiver1.csv
Name: names, dtype: object
1      After_Source1_Receiver2.csv
3     Before_Source1_Receiver2.csv
5    During1_Source1_Receiver2.csv
7    During2_Source1_Receiver2.csv
Name: names, dtype: object
```

Comment: That is great! However, is there anyway to sort them as I have shown above in Group 1 and Group 2? I would like the sequence to go "Before", "During1", "During2", "After". My end goal is to import the grouped files and concatenate the ".csv" files in their own groups. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: it does but I think you can take it from here, your initial question showed no attempt and I think you should attempt this extra request yourself since the question only asks to sort by numbers after `Source` and `Name`

Comment: Thanks for your help.